# Why is a $q promise returning an $http promise as a payload?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-services

I have a promise chain which has to call `$http` partway down the chain and pass the resulting  promise to the next handler. The problem is my `.then()` success function appears to be wrapping the returned `$http` promise in another promise, resulting in my http promise being treated as a payload. So when it resolves in the next link in the chain I get a promise rather than the http response.

```
var statusPromise = Auth.getUserStatus();

var tokenPromise = statusPromise.then(function(status) {
    if (status && status.accesstoken) {
        return status.accesstoken;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});

var httpPromise = tokenPromise.then(function(accesstoken) {
    console.log('access token', accesstoken);
    var params = {
        page: page,
        limit: limit
    };

    if (accesstoken) {
        params.accesstoken = accesstoken;
    }

    return $http.get(apiUrl + 'scenes/' + filter + '/', {
        data: $.param(params),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
});

var doMoreStuffPromise = httpPromise.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response); // this logs the promise as the payload, not the http response
    return response.data;
});

return doMoreStuffPromise;
```

How can I chain the `$http` promise in my chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was happening much further up the chain than I expected. It turns out that my Auth service had a bug:

```
this.getUserStatus = function() {
    $.when(...); // woops, no $q
};
```

Should have been:

```
this.getUserStatus = function() {
    $q.when(...);
};
```

I accidentally forgot `$q` and since `$.when()` is a legitimate jQuery function for creating promises, nothing failed outright. However, due to the slight differences in how angular and jquery promises work, one wrapped the other instead of unwrapping.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen this problem in the wild, and had considered it purely theoretical :-)

Answer (score 1):

`$http` calls return promises, and promises recursively assimilate... the problem is not with promises. The problem is with the `$http` API in particular. In fact, it's quite impossible for a Promises/A+ implementation like $q to return a thenable without unwrapping it.

If you use `.then` (in the success case) it acts in a different way than if you use `.success`, apart from `.success` not chaining, it [resolves with `.data`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L654):

Your code should do the same:

```
var doMoreStuffPromise = httpPromise.then(function(rep) {
    console.log(resp.data);  // now, your actual data
    return resp.data;
});
```

Comment: That's what I've done, I've just named the callback variable being passed `data` in my case. If I do what you suggest, `resp` is still a promise that's been wrapped by the previous `tokenPromise.then()`. A promise as a payload inside another promise.

Comment: I've also updated the code in my question to illustrate this more clearly with less ambiguous nomenclature.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because your remarks about Promises/A+ implementations more correct than I think you intended. JQuery promises aren't A+ and do NOT unwrap, hence the very similar looking, but wrapped, behaviour.